# Stop Excel opening yet another Outlook window

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have Excel vba macro to open specific Outlook inbox subfolders but the Outlook sub-folder opens in a new Outlook window.

This has the result that if i don't manually close the new window, then after running the macro several times I have multiple Outlook windows open.

How can I modify the code so that Outlook simply navigates to the required subfolder in it's existing single window instead, please?

Currently the new Outlook window opens on top of my Excel spreadsheet. When running the macro, I would like the current instance of Outlook to go to the required subfolder and for it to apprear on top of the Excel spreadsheet.

I did not write the code below. I have incorporated the code below into a larger macro but the rest is irrelevant.

```
Dim MyOutLookApp As Object
Dim MyNameSpace As Object
Dim MyFolder As Object
Dim This As Variant

 '// Late Binding
Set MyOutLookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") '''I have also tried using = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application").... no change
Set MyNameSpace = MyOutLookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
On Error GoTo ErrFlder


Set MyFolder = MyNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFldr.olFolderInbox)
Set MyFolder = MyFolder.Folders 
Set This = MyFolder
Set This = MyFolder(strJobName)  '''strJobname is a string picked up from elsewhere. It is simply the name of the inbox subfolder I want to go to.

This.display
End Sub
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel VBA to detect if Outlook is open, if its not ,then open it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28936757/excel-vba-to-detect-if-outlook-is-open-if-its-not-then-open-it)

Comment: See my answer below- is that what your trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

From my answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49030096/8112776):  <sub>(a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A8112776%20outlook), actually)</sub>

> When working with applications such as Excel it's important to make
>   sure the application object is properly `.Quit` / `.Close`'d when
>   finished with them, (and to `Set` all objects to `Nothing`), otherwise
>   there's a risk of inadvertently having multiple instances running,
>   which can lead to memory leaks, which leads to crashes and potential
>   data loss.
>
> To check if there is an existing instance of Outlook, use this
>   function:
>
> ```
> Function IsOutlookOpen()
> 'returns TRUE if Outlook is running
>
>     Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
>
>     On Error Resume Next
>     Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
>     On Error GoTo 0
>
>     If olApp Is Nothing Then
>         IsOutlookOpen= False
>     Else
>         IsOutlookOpen= True
>     End If
>
> End Function
> ```

More about opening a **new vs. existing instances** of Office applications from the Source: **[Ron de Bruin](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/openclose.htm)**

Comment: When you have a hummer, everything looks like a nail. I posted this comment in response to your answer in another thread, so I'll post it again: Absolutely not - Outlook is a singleton. No matter how many times you create an instance of the Outlook.Application object, it returns the same object from the same outlook.exe process.

Answer (score 0):

*If you simply want to navigate to the subfolder in it's existing single window then  work with [Application.ActiveExplorer Method (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/application-activeexplorer-method-outlook) with [CurrentFolder Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211818(v=office.11).aspx)*

*The following example with activate the **`SubFolder`** name **"Temp"** under **`Inbox`** in same window application*

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Example()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNS As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    '// Ref to Outlook Inbox
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
    Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("Temp")

    If Not SubFolder Is Nothing Then
        Set olApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = SubFolder
    Else
        MsgBox "SubFolder Not Found", vbInformation
    End If
End Sub
```

> *[MSDN: Early and Late Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/early-late-binding/)*

Comment: olApp.ActiveExplorer will be null if Outlook was not running before this code is executed.

Answer (score 0):

Your code always calls `MAPIFolder.Display`, so you get a new Explorer window every time.
Do the following instead

```
if MyOutLookApp.ActiveExplorer Is Nothing Then
  This.Display
Else
  set MyOutLookApp.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder = This
End If
```