# Outlook VBA code is not exiting

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, exit

I have a code that runs every morning when I got a certain email.
The code updates an SQL table, opens an Excel file and runs a macro in it.
The code is called through a rule which triggers the script.

The "problem" is: if Outlook remains opened until the next day when the same code is called, I get an error "the remote server machine does not exist or is unavailable", so, the solution would be close Outlook app and reopen it later. As it runs on a server where I don't have sufficient privileges to run scripts through "Task Scheduler", I needed to either: arrange to close automatically Outlook after the code finishes or close Outlook manually every single day (weekends included :)).

Obviously, I tried to insert this task in the code, but it never works. It never shows any error as well. It simply ignores the command to exit the app.

```
Sub RunReports(MyMail As MailItem)

Dim strID As String
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim AttFile As Outlook.Attachment
Dim emDateTime As Date
Dim WhereToSaveAttachment As String
Dim FileAddr As String
Dim ExApp As Excel.Application
Dim ExWbk As Workbook

strID = MyMail.EntryID
Set objMail = Application.Session.GetItemFromID(strID)
Subj = objMail.Subject
emDateTime = objMail.ReceivedTime
WhereToSaveAttachment = "\network_address"

Set ExApp = Excel.Application

For Each AttFile In objMail.Attachments

    FileAddr = WhereToSaveAttachment & "\" & AttFile.DisplayName
    AttFile.SaveAsFile FileAddr
    Set ExWbk = ExApp.Workbooks.Open("x:\filename1.xlsm")
    Result = ExWbk.Application.Run("filename1.xlsm!FillingReportData", FileAddr, objMail.SentOn)
    ExWbk.Close True
    Set ExWbk = Nothing

Next
Set ExApp = Nothing

If Len(FileAddr) > 2 Then Kill FileAddr
Set objMail = Nothing
Set ExApp = Nothing

Set ExApp = Excel.Application
Set ExWbk = ExApp.Workbooks.Open("\\address\filename2.xlsm")
ExWbk.Application.Run ("RunAllReports")
ExWbk.Close True
Set ExWbk = Nothing

Set ExApp = Nothing
Application.Quit
```

Could anyone advise on that?

Comment: I suspect that you are not checking if Outlook is already open? [Try This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28936757/excel-vba-to-detect-if-outlook-is-open-if-its-not-then-open-it). Also, you don't need to create an instance of excel (`Set ExApp = Excel.Application`), you are already in excel. Have a look at `Application` option

Comment: Thanks! Actually, this code is running within Outlook, that's why I need to set ExApp and don't need to verify Outlook. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Which line of your script throws the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just be tricky. In the last part of this process, modify the macro to add a call to a BAT file. This BAT file must contain this text:

`TASKKILL /IM OUTLOOK.EXE /F`.

To create this BAT file, just create a normal TXT, and then change the extension to BAT. Name it something like CLOSE OUTLOOK.BAT

To call the file from VBA, just use:

`Shell ("c:\fULLPATHTOFILE\CLOSE OUTLOOK.BAT")
DoEvents`

This will force Outlook to close. And then use normal `Application.Quit` to finish Excel.

Give it a try.

Comment: I haven't tried it before. Good idea! Thanks. Tomorrow I'll be back here to tell you if it worked ;)